# Cycling an array

Tags: arrays

I've recently done a project on creating traffic lights that cycle on the click of a button in HTML, however when I attempt(ed) this with a text list it's not working. The aim is to cycle through the list of people in order, starting with the first in the list, yet it's not working! Any ideas on how to fix it?

Full Script:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>PRIORITY: ICT DEPT</legend>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <button onclick="change()">></button>
</fieldset>
```

```
priority=0

var ictTeachers = ["Mrs. West", "Mr. Mulligan", "Mrs. Davidson","Mr. Rowan" "Mr. Demolder" "Mr. Schander" "Mr. Blackwell"];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ictTeachers[1];

function change() {
    if(priority==0) {
    document.getElementById("demo").src = ictTeachers[1]
    position=1;

    }else if(priority==1) {
    document.getElementById("demo").src = ictTeachers[2]
    position=2;

    }else if(priority==2) {
    document.getElementById("demo").src = ictTeachers[3]
    position=3;

    }else if(priority==3) {
    document.getElementById("demo").src = ictTeachers[4]
    position=4
    }else if(priority==4) {
    document.getElementById("demo").src = ictTeachers[5]
    position=5;

    }else if(priority==5) {
    document.getElementById("demo").src = ictTeachers[6]
    position=6;

    }else if(priority==6) {
    document.getElementById("demo").src = ictTeachers[0]
    position=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: "It's not working" is never a good hint. *Never* use it. Describe the behaviour you're expecting, what you got instead, and maybe what you think it's the problem.

Comment: You are testing `priority` but changing `position`...

Comment: There is a pattern here, you can remove all the *if..else* branches with: `var x = (priority + 1) % ictTeachers.length; document.getElementById('demo').src = ictTeachers[x]; position = x;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason is that you are using `.src` when you should be using `.innerHTML` or `.innerText`

However, you seem to complicate your life. You should try to simplify your code.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/13zrL1s1/)

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ictTeachers[1];

var position = 0;
function change() {

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ictTeachers[position+1]
    position=(position + 1) % ictTeachers.length;
}
```

You should also ensure that you don't have syntax errors. You forgot some comas in the array you made.

```
var ictTeachers = ["Mrs. West", "Mr. Mulligan", "Mrs. Davidson","Mr. Rowan", "Mr. Demolder", "Mr. Schander", "Mr. Blackwell"];
```

Comment: Great solution, adapted for personal use. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing priority variable

```
if(priority==0) {
document.getElementById("demo").src = ictTeachers[1]
position=1;

}
```

And `priority` value is still 0, try to rename all variables `position` to `priority`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your preference is, you could use a for loop to cycle through all of the teachers in ictTeachers.

[w3schools](http://w3schools)

Really any type of loop would solve your problem.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's barely a comment.

Comment: I thought it answered the question?

Comment: It has assisted me with similar contextual solutions though!